# How to print content getting from JavaScript to html

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I used JavaScript to get data from database `Parse.com` .Also, I used `html` to create my webpage

My problem is I can not print the data from JavaScript to html. My code with more detailed as follow :

My `<script>` which placed in `<head>` tag of html :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >

 Parse.initialize("Key", "Key");
        var order = Parse.Object.extend("MainBranch");
        var query = new Parse.Query(order);
        var orid ;

        query.find({
        success: function(results) {

        alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " Orders."); //here every things workings well which mean it reached to Parse.com (database) successfully  
        },
        error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
        });


        query.get("ZL8OcUjnJX", {
        success: function(object) {
         orid= object.get("OrderId");    

        },

        error: function(object, error) {
        // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
        }
        });

        function showinfo(){

        document.write(orid);

        }
</script>
```

Part of the `html` body is as follow:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked"</td> 
    <td id="intro"> 
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
          showinfo();   // here it printed as undefined but it has to print real data which have gotten from Parse.com by script    
   </script> 
</td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: Have you checked whether `orid` exists with `console.log(orid)`?

Comment: I don't know anything about Parse.com, but my guess is query.get is an async function and you're trying to reference orid before it's set.

Comment: orid is a variable that I defined it @derek_duncan

Comment: ummm so do you have any idea how can I reference it after it set ? @BarbaraLaird

Comment: In your success function, do a document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = orid;  and get rid of the call to showinfo() in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <script type="text/javascript" >

 Parse.initialize("Key", "Key");
        var order = Parse.Object.extend("MainBranch");
        var query = new Parse.Query(order);
        var orid ;

        query.find({
        success: function(results) {

        alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " Orders."); //here every things workings well which mean it reached to Parse.com (database) successfully  
        },
        error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
        });


        query.get("ZL8OcUjnJX", {
        success: function(object) {
         orid= object.get("OrderId");    
         document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = orid;
        },

        error: function(object, error) {
        // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
        }
        });

</script>
```

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked"</td> 
    <td id="intro"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is *put the whole thing inside the function*. I don't believe `orid` is defined when you run `showinfo()'.

#### Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 function showinfo(callback) {
   Parse.initialize("Key", "Key");
        var order = Parse.Object.extend("MainBranch");
        var query = new Parse.Query(order);
        var orid ;

        query.find({
        success: function(results) {

        alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " Orders."); //here every things workings well which mean it reached to Parse.com (database) successfully  
        },
        error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
        });


        query.get("ZL8OcUjnJX", {
        success: function(object) {
         orid= object.get("OrderId");    
         return callback(orid);
        },

        error: function(object, error) {
         return false;
        // error is an instance of Parse.Error.
        }
    });
 };
</script>
```

**Then for you HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      showinfo(function(result) {
        document.write(result);
      });
</script>
```

Comment: It is running but document.write() deleted everything to print data which is saved in var orid  @derek_duncan

Comment: Sure thing @Noha If you can learn how to use callback functions like I did here, it will help you tremendously down the road when you meet async functions :)